# xsl:sort inhomogeneous elements in xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, sorting, xslt-1.0

I have a set of elements with different attributes, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=utf-8"?>
<root>
  <elem at="4" iterate="third" />
  <foo/>
  <elem at="1" iterate="first" />
  <bar/>
  <elem start="3" end="9" iterate="second" />
</root>
```

I want to iterate over the `elem` tags, so I specified the `for-each` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/elem">
```

so far so good, but now I want to *sort* these elements, according to their `@at` and `@start` field, while each `elem` is guaranteed to have *either* `@at` *or* `@start`. I annotated in the `@iterate` attribute how I want the tags to be iterated over (just for the sake of clarity here).

My approach was this

```
<xsl:sort select="@at or @start" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
```

But that doesn't seem to work as intended as elements with an `@at` attribute seem to be prioritised over elements with an `@start` attribute.

So, how can I tell XSLT (1.0) not to distinguish between the name of the attribute that is set and simply sort according to its respective value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not far off. Try using the union operator |

```
<xsl:sort select="@at|@start" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="elem">
            <xsl:sort select="@at|@start" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <elem at="1" iterate="first"></elem>
   <elem start="3" end="9" iterate="second"></elem>
   <elem at="4" iterate="third"></elem>
</root>
```